# How to view the full background image of a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

I just wondered if there is a trick to show the full-sized background image of a YouTube channel.

With thumbnails, there is the trick to view the image and change the URL (from `*/mqdefault.jpg` to `*/maxresdefault.jpg`)

Now, the channel's background image is in reality a really big 16:9 image (I think the biggest versions of this can normally be seen on Smart-TV apps). But on a normal browser only a small subset of this image is even delivered to the client. I hoped that there might be a way to tamper with the image URL (like the thumbnail-trick) to see the full image.

Has anybody an idea?

---

A small example:

The LaserUnicorn channel has this background image (got the URL from Firfox's "inspect" function): https://yt3.ggpht.com/-C9gaunpPNo8/VYGWj4xT-uI/AAAAAAAAAGo/pUPfpvLF7Dc/w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/comicon_youtube3.jpg

Comment: You could use inspect element on the image and copy and paste the url and look at the image that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Erik's method](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91660/354) is correct, but you can simply delete the `-fcroped64=.-nd-.-.-no` feature from the URL, then you'll get the picture with its original size.

Example:

- the URL of the cropped picture: `https://yt3.ggpht.com/-C9gaunpPNo8/VYGWj4xT-uI/AAAAAAAAAGo/pUPfpvLF7Dc/w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/comicon_youtube3.jpg`

  - the part that should be deleted:  `-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no` (even if you delete `/comicon_youtube3.jpg` from the URL, you'll still be able to see the picture)
  - the URL of the un-cropped picture: `https://yt3.ggpht.com/-C9gaunpPNo8/VYGWj4xT-uI/AAAAAAAAAGo/pUPfpvLF7Dc/w2120/comicon_youtube3.jpg`

p.s., in the above URL the number "2120" is the width of the picture; because "w" stands for width. And yes we can also add "h"; which stands for height obviously!

For instance, let say that we want the height of the above picture to be 500, then all what we have to do is to add `-h500` after `w2120` to get `/w2120-h500/`, then the height of the picture will be displayed with 500 in height.

Answer (score 8):

Okay I found it, and if anybody is interested:

The URL sends an fcrop64 value. (The value in `.*fcrop64=(.*)-nd-.*`)

In my example it is at `1,00005a57ffffa5a8`. By changing it simply to `1`, the cropping is removed and you get the full image.

---

For the example: https://yt3.ggpht.com/-C9gaunpPNo8/VYGWj4xT-uI/AAAAAAAAAGo/pUPfpvLF7Dc/w2120-fcrop64=1-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/comicon_youtube3.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The most non-tinkery method around at the moment is going to the YouTube Gaming site of the channel and scrolling up. So for the example mentioned in the OP:

https://youtube.com/LaserUnicorns → [https://`gaming.`youtube.com/LaserUnicorns](https://gaming.youtube.com/LaserUnicorns)